# Declaring multiple audio files with ID

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am declaring many audio files for use in my website. Here is the current format:

```
<audio type="audio/mpeg" id="1" src="articles/2013-12-22-BrainstormingCreativity/v1.mp3"></audio>
<audio type="audio/mpeg" id="2" src="articles/2013-12-22-BrainstormingCreativity/v2.mp3"></audio>
<audio type="audio/mpeg" id="3" src="articles/2013-12-22-BrainstormingCreativity/v3.mp3"></audio>
```

I am trying to clean up the code. I have played with several formats along these lines:

```
<audio>
 <source src="articles/2013-12-22-BrainstormingCreativity/v4.mp3" id="4" type="audio/mpeg" />
 <source src="articles/2013-12-22-BrainstormingCreativity/v5.mp3" id="5" type="audio/mpeg" />
 <source src="articles/2013-12-22-BrainstormingCreativity/v6.mp3" id="6" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

However, the files no longer play. Is it possible to declare audio files this way? Or is there another way I can clean up this part of my code?

Comment: I'd imagine you need to declare the type first

Comment: Files no longer play... all of them or the last two?

Comment: For reference, IDs can't start with numerals.

Comment: you want to play 2 audio files ? is that the problem ?

Comment: I tried starting it with the type, and that didn't work either.
The files play with the first format, but not with the second one. Meaning 1, 2, and 3 play, but not 4, 5, or 6.
As far as starting with numerals, it works properly with the first format used for 1, 2, and 3.
I have many files that are used on the page, and I am just trying to find a more compact and clean way to declare them.